# Deploy War on Tomcat Running in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, jsf

Iam Trying to Deploy JSF application on Tomcat9 running in docker

this is my docker file

```
From tomcat:9.0.65-jdk11-corretto-al2
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
EXPOSE 8060
COPY ROOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

When i build the docker file The application starts inside Tomcat but it is stuck without errors in logs

[image: Docker Container Logs]

Please Help what the problem might be

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Looks like a DB connectivity issue.

Comment: Can you provide the `docker run` command as well how you are trying to access the tomcat? But make sure that you map the port to host computer.